# HTML | CSS: Issues with hamburger menu

Tags: html, css

My name is Troy, I have been trying to create a Hamburger menu for ages now on HTML and CSS.

I found a tutorial on YouTube, and it worked fine, till I added `<nav></nav>` below it. I will include the link to the youtube video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMTs8tAapnQ).

So basically the issue is that I tried adding a `<nav></nav>` under the header, and then when I click on the hamburger menu, It destroys the entire thing, until I close the hamburger menu again: There are loads of comments on the video saying that I should add a `min-height: 70px;` in the CSS. Tried it, but it did not do anything. I appreciate the reader who is reading this to spend time trying to find a way how to help me <3

Also, here you have my code of HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home | Tingle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
    <div class="nav">
      <h1>Tingle</h1>
      <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Documentation</a>
        <a href="#">Invite</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="discord-header">
      <h1>Join the Discord Support Server!</h1>
      <p>If you need support, or send suggestions, or want to talk about Tingle, just join our discord server!</p>
      <button type="button" name="button"><a href="#">Invite</a></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here you have the CSS code:

```
body{
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav{
  background: #5fffcb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
  text-align: right;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.nav h1{
  font-size: 25px;
  float: left;
    line-height: 70px;
    padding-left: 20px;
      margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.menu{
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.menu a{
  clear: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #282828;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

label{
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: none;
  width: 26px;
  float: right;
}

#toggle{
  display: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){

  nav{
    height: auto;
 min-height: 70px;
 line-height: 70px;
  }
  label{
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .menu{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  .menu a{
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
    margin: 0;
  }

  #toggle:checked + .menu{
    display: block;
}
```

And here you have an image on what is actually happening:
[CSS Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOj9P.png)

-Troy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to take the [tour] and peruse the [ask] page to gain an understanding of how the site works.

Comment: May be a typo, but I don't see an open body tag.

Comment: You could also use Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com). It's easy to implement and allows you to provide a responsive design, which includes the hamburger menu.

Comment: I will try that, thanks. I just added an Image to clearly show what is happening. Also, I am not so sure how to install and utilize Bootstrap.

Comment: Include their required css and js libraries on your page: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/  Then follow the example for the navbar with hamburger: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found a solution to your problem. Initially, I suspected something to do with z-index since it looks like it's below the other text. However, turns out you have a few problems:

1. Your menu is in the flow of the document. It's pushing the rest of your content downwards.
2. Your menu covers up the topbar when it's expanded, making it impossible to retract once it's expanded.
3. Your menu has no background color, so everything beneath it shows up when it's expanded.

Under your @media .menu CSS, you need to have the following code:

```
 .menu{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 top: 72px;
 z-index: 5;
 background-color: #fff;
}
```

Position: fixed takes it out of the document flow. Top: 72px makes sure it doesn't cover the topbar. Z-index: 5 and background-color: #fff make it appear on top of the rest of your page. Now it looks like this:

[image: fixed image]

Try it out yourself and let me know if it fixes your problem or if you still need help. No need to jump to Bootstrap or any complicated frameworks - it's a basic CSS implementation and you were just about there, just missing a few lines of code.